# Is $\sin^{-1}(\sin x) = x - \pi$ or $\pi - x$ for $x \in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

Consider $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$ for $x\in[\pi/2 , 3\pi/2]$ .
Clearly,

$$\pi/2 \le x \le 3\pi/2\tag{1}$$

Subtracting $\pi$, we get:

$$-\pi/2 \le x - \pi \le \pi/2$$

Now, the term $(x-\pi)$ had come in the range of $\sin^{-1}(x)$. Hence,

$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x-\pi$ for all $x\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\tag{2}$

Once more consider the inequation (1):
$$\pi/2 \le x \le 3\pi/2$$

Multiplying this by $(-1)$, we get;

$$-\pi/2 \ge -x \ge -3\pi/2$$

Adding $\pi$ in this gives:

$$\pi/2 \ge \pi-x \ge -\pi/2;$$ which can be re-written as;

$$-\pi/2 \le \pi-x \le π/2$$

Now, the term $(\pi -x)$ has come within range of $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$.  Hence,

$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)) = \pi -x$ for all $x\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\tag{3}$

But (2) and (3) are contradictory. Can anyone tell whether $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)) =  x-\pi$ or $\pi-x$ and also explain why.

Comment: My textbook says it is π - x. But I don't know why x-π is wrong.

Comment: This is because $\sin x=\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\sin x≠\sin (x-\pi)$.

Comment: Yes I know this and the first proof should be incorrect . But I am unable to spot mistake in the first proof above . Can you please tell which line is incorrect in the first proof? Thanks

Comment: We write $\sin x=\sin(\pi-x)=\pi-x$. Note that for the first one, $\sin x = —\sin (x-\pi)$ so $\sin^{-1}\sin x=—(x-\pi)=\pi-x$.

Comment: Again. I understand that sin(x) = sin(π-x). But x- π and π - x, both belong to range of $sin^{-1}x$ . So why can't I take in both cases?

Comment: I want to clarify that I can understand it in the way you told, but my problem is to spot that which line is incorrect in above proof. Thanks

Comment: Because $\arcsin(\sin \color{red}A)=\color{red}A$ for A in the range. Both the argument of the $\arcsin(\sin)$ function and the final result must be the same.

Comment: Inside you can get either x or $\pi-x$. You can’t get $x-\pi$ inside the $\arcsin(\sin) $ function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138796/discussion-between-an-elephant-and-insipidintegrator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first method we have

$$\frac \pi 2 \le x \le \frac 3 2 \pi \implies -\frac \pi 2 \le x-\pi \le \frac \pi 2 $$

then we can conclude that

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin (x-\pi))=x-\pi$$

but not $$\color{red}{\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x-\pi}$$

To proceed by this way, we can observe that $$\sin (x-\pi) = -\sin (\pi-x)= -\sin x$$

and since $\forall \theta \in \mathbb R$ we have $$\sin^{-1}(-\sin \theta)= -\sin^{-1}(\sin \theta)$$ we can conclude that

$$\sin^{-1}(-\sin x)=x-\pi \implies \sin^{-1}(\sin x)=\pi-x$$

Comment: Thanks it helped. I realise my mistake.

Comment: Well done! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 4):

> Let $x\in[\pi/2 , 3\pi/2].$ $$-\pi/2 \le x - \pi \le \pi/2$$
>
> Now, the term $(x-\pi)$ has come in the range of $\sin^{-1}(x)$.
> Hence,
>
> $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x-\pi\;\text{ for all }x\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\tag{2}$

The above argument is invalid; here's an analogous illogical argument:

- Let $x\in[-1,1].$ Since $x$ is in the range of $\sin(x),$ for each $x\in[-1,1],$ $$\sin x=x.$$

> $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)) = \pi -x$ for all $x\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\tag{3}$

This is correct.

Comment: Yes Thanks. I realise my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that we cannot necessarily plug any value in the argument of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ if it fit inside the range . The actual mistake I was doing after finding the range of argument is this :

$-π/2 ≤ x - π ≤ π/2$

And

For $x-π$ to hold the equality, it must satisfy :

$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x)) = \sin^{-1}(\sin(x-π))$ ;

which is incorrect.

And thus, $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$ = π - x for x $\in[π/2,3π/2]$

Comment: I suggest you accept this answer.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thanks. But I think that other answers are clear as well. It is of course you, who made me understand :)

Comment: I only said this because your self-answer was the first answer, so I figured that it would be easy to knock the question off the “unanswered” list because you had understood. I agree, all the other answers are well crafted and comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sin^{-1}(\sin x)=\theta\
\implies \sin\theta=\sin x\implies \theta=n\pi+(-1)^nx, n\in\mathbb Z$
Put $n=1$ to see that $\theta=\pi-x$.

Comment: Thanks it helped.